# Django. Q Query on categorys

Tags: python, django, django-q

I have a categories model defined as:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        name = unicode(self.name)
        if self.parent:
            name =  unicode(self.parent) + u'-->' + name
        return name
```

the categories may have up to 3 levels of parents (Category 1 -> Category 2 -> Category 3 -> Category 4)

I need to see all items in my database, but exclude base Category 14 if and only if the location == Ebay.

I was using:

```
    query = Q(category__number=14) & ~Q(location__name="EBAY")
    queryset.exclude(query)
```

If an item has a category of 14->15->42->16, the category number returned is 16. I need the first category level, but I do not know how many parents there are. There can be none, or up to 3 parents.

How would I edit the query to look back through my category tree?

Answer (score 0):

Django don't do SQL independent tree crawling but models tree libs are here.

- https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt
- https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/

For recursive lookup, you may want to use raw sql or a library as django-mptt or django-treebeard.

mptt seems to be more up to date.